# Storing and selecting multiple ids in database

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have a newsletter component and users can subscribe to multiple newsletters. It is stored in the table of the subscribers like this: 4,8,11 (these are the id's of the newsletters the subscriber is subscribed to)

To select the subscribers of a newsletter I use:

```
"SELECT * FROM #__newsl_subscribers WHERE newslids LIKE '%" . (int) $id."%'";
```

When I want to select all users that receive newsletter with id 1, the user that receives newsletter 11 (or 12, 10 etc..) is also selected. And that's the problem.

Is there a select-statement for this? Otherwise I have to store the id's with brackets around them [1],[11], etc...

Comment: Why, oh why, oh why, oh why do people never normalise their databases

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You really should avoid solutions where several ids are stored in one field. Instead you should use foreign keys and, like in your case for n:m relationships, relationship tables.
n:m-relationships are these where *a* can have multiple *b* and vice versa.

I would do the following:

Table "subscriber":
No information about newsletters

Table "newsletter":
No information about subscribers

**New table "newsletter_subscriber"**:
Field: subscriber_id
Field: newsletter_id
Both fields are foreign keys (references to the primary key of another table).

To select all subscribers of a specific newsletter, you can use this statement:

```
SELECT s.* FROM subscriber s
INNER JOIN newsletter_subscriber ns ON ns.subscriber_id = s.id
WHERE ns.newsletter_id = <newsletter id>
```

And vice versa, to select all newsletters of a specific subscriber:

```
SELECT n.* FROM newsletter n
INNER JOIN newsletter_subscriber ns ON ns.newsletter_id = n.id
WHERE ns.subscriber_id = <subscriber id>
```

*BTW I should appologize for not answering your original question. Maybe you know everything about database normalization, having other reasons for these ids stored in one field?*

Comment: OK, thanks! So this means creating a separate table for the relation?

Comment: @Bert - it does, but it will make things so much simpler for you in the long run

Comment: Yes, that's true for all n:m cases. This gives you way more flexibility and stability when inserting, updating and deleting relations between the two tables.

Comment: Great, sounds like the solution I need. Thanks!